# Center table and make one row different

Tags: latex

I've got a table like:

```
\begin{center} 
\begin{table} [h]
\caption{some caption.} 
    \label{tab: 1}
\begin{tabular}{||c | c c c c c||}
 \hline
Team &Goal& SOG& SA& Hits& Possession\\ 
 \hline\hline
 \textbf{Team1} & 54 & 171 &    464 & 941 & 11:46:33
 \\ 
 \hline
 \textbf{Team2} & 89 & 237 & 502 & 861 & 10:28:02 \\ 
\hline \hline
Per cent split\\
 \hline \hline
 \textbf{Team1}&  38\% &    42\% &  48\% &  52\% &  53\%  \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{center}
```

And I cannot seem to center it. I've wrapped it in a \center but it still pushes to the left of the page. I am also wondering how to alter the row with `Per cent split`: ideally I'd want the text centered on the row and the row to end in the same manner that the table does, right now it does not do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You center instructions must be within the `table` environment. However you shouldn't use the `center` environment. This will add additional vertical spacing. You should use `\centering` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

%\begin{center} 
\begin{table} [h]
\caption{some caption.} 
    \label{tab: 1}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{||c | c c c c c||}
 \hline
Team &Goal& SOG& SA& Hits& Possession\\ 
 \hline\hline
 \textbf{Team1} & 54 & 171 &    464 & 941 & 11:46:33
 \\ 
 \hline
 \textbf{Team2} & 89 & 237 & 502 & 861 & 10:28:02 \\ 
\hline \hline
\multicolumn{6}{||c||}{Per cent split}\\
 \hline \hline
 \textbf{Team1}&  38\% &    42\% &  48\% &  52\% &  53\%  \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
%\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]